How to Display Data from Multiple Devices Together in a ThingsBoard Timeseries Table Widget?
Question:
I am working with ThingsBoard, an open-source IoT platform, and I have multiple devices sending timeseries data to the platform. I am using the timeseries table widget to visualize this data.
Current Setup:
I have the timeseries table widget set up to display data from my devices.
Currently, the widget displays the data in the form of tabs, with each tab representing data from a single device.
Objective:
I want to customize the timeseries table widget to display data from all my devices together in a single table, without using tabs. This way, I can see and compare the data from all devices in one unified view.
Is it possible to configure the timeseries table widget in ThingsBoard to display data from multiple devices together in a single table without using tabs?
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Yes, you just have to create an alias that contains multiple devices and use this alias in your timeseries table widget.
For example, you have device1, device2 and device3 with device profile "mydevice" (device profile = device type). So those 3 devices have same profile.
Now you can create an alias of "Device Type" (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/ui/aliases/#device-type) and select your device type (device profile).
Use the alias that you have created in your timeseries table widget, now you can see all data (device1, device2, device3) in the same table.
You can use other types of aliases to select multiple devices, choose which one best fits your situation. (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/ui/aliases/)

Thank you for the explanation.However, with this method, I can only view the devices' data in multiple tabs and not in a single tab.
I'm looking to consolidate all of the devices' data into a single tab rather than having it spread across multiple tabs.
